# Pay with Passcode not calling didAuthorizePayment

Tags: swift

I have integrated Apple Pay and it works successfully as expected on device. However using the simulator when I click the "Pay with Passcode" button in the presented view it never calls the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate.didAuthorizePaymnent`delegate method rather always only calls `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate. paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish`. Any thoughts why?

I'm using Xcode 10.3 with the iOS simulators running iOS 12.4. I'm positive this was working as expected in Xcode 10.2.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be an Apple bug.We are experiencing the same issue with the iOS 12.4 simulator (16G73). It works as expected on the device (16G77) and on the iOS 12.2 simulator (16E226).

Comment: I have raised a bug report for this. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/7020710

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should probably make sure you have followed all the rules and requirements in order to test said item here on the [Apple Developer Apple Pay Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/implementation/).

Furthermore, without seeing your code, I cannot see what you did correctly, here is a another [website](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2113-apple-pay-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-005) that may help you call that specifically this section of the link!

Hope this fixes your problem!